# interrupt next-function when iterating large files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program which loads data from defferent file-types. For each supported file type I have iterators. So I can go through the data of a file with for example:

```
it = MyIterator("filename")
for data in it:
    DoSomethingWithData(data)
```

Now I want to have the possibility to stop this iteration. This is genereally no problem, but in some cases a call to the iterators `next()`-function takes very very long, because there is no readable data in the file. In those cases the iterator goes through the whole file without finding anything, until it reaches the end and raises StopIteration.

So I want to have the opportunity to stop - or better interrupt - the next-function, without any idea how to do it. I think I have to use something like threads, but I can't kill threads either. Something likethis would be nice:

```
def Iterate():
    it = MyIterator("filename")
    for data in it:
        self.t0 = time.time()
        DoSomethingWithData(data)

iterationThread = threading.Thread(target=Iterate)
iterationThread.start()

self.t0 = time.time()
maxWaitingTime = 10.
while iterationThread.IsAlive():
    if self.t0 - time.time() > maxWaitingTime:
        KillThread(iterationThread)
```

That's generally what I want to have, but I have no function `KillThread` of course...

So has anyone an idea how to handle something like that? And it is no possibility to change the iterators itself...

Comment: Very interesting question. I usually use asynchronous I/O where this problem is trivial to solve. But that wouldn't work in this case where the Iterators cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

`MyIterator` sounds as you had control over it.

In this case, you could redesign it so that the `next()` method returns early if there are no data, returning `None`.

Your loop would then look like

```
for data in it:
    if data is not None:
        DoSomethingWithData(data)
```

Comment: Yes, `MyIterator` is something I have control over. But it is not only one iterator, it is one dynamically chosen, out of many. As I already said, changing the iterators itself is no option. It is at least one iterator for every data-type, every iterator is working different and generally not written by myself.